# How to add the product info detail tab in the product page hyva theme

Tags: tabs, magento2.4.6, product-detail-page, hyva, product-details

Add the product info detail tab in the product page hyva theme (same as default magento)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check these examples [here](https://codebase-frontend-library.github.io/codebase-4/docs/8-alpinejs-components/alpinejs-tabs/)

Extend **Magento_Catalog::catalog_product_view.xml**:

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <container name="tabs.switcher" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="flex" />
        <container name="tabs.elements" />
    </referenceBlock>

    <!-- move the elements inside the tabs -->
    <!-- example: -->
    <move element="description" destination="tabs.elements" before="-" />
    <!-- set a custom identifier for the tabs -->
    <referenceBlock name="description">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="tab_id" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <!-- set the button text -->
    <referenceContainer name="tabs.switcher">
        <block template="Magento_Catalog::/view/sections/tabs/labels.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="tab_id" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                <argument name="tab_label" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Create **Magento_Catalog::/view/sections/tabs/labels.phtml**:

```
<?php

$tabId = $block->getData('tab_id');
$tabLabel = $block->getData('tab_label');
?>
<label @click="activeTab = <?= $tabId ?>"
       class="tab-control"
       :class="{ 'active': activeTab === <?= $tabId ?> }"
>
    <?= $tabLabel ?>
</label>
```

Finally, you would need to update the main Block **Magento_Catalog::product/view/sections/product-sections.phtml**:

Add the Alpine initializer to the outer `div`:

```
x-data="{ activeTab:  0 }"
```

Add the new containers for the tabs buttons and the tabs inside the `div`:

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('tabs.switcher') ?>

<?php $tabs = $block->getLayout()->getChildBlocks('tabs.elements') ?>
<?php foreach ($tabs as $tab): ?>
    <div x-show.transition.in.opacity.duration.600="activeTab === <?= $tab->getData('tab_id') ?>">
        <?= $tab->toHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

- Please note that the above code is not tested and requires clean up & escaping

Answer (score 0):

2.Extend Hyva-default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/sections/product-sections.phtml

getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info_hyva', 'getChildHtml');
?>

```
<?php $layout = $block->getLayout(); ?>
<div class="product info detailed" x-data="{ activeTab: '<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($layout->getElementAlias($detailedInfoGroup[0])) ?>' }">
    <div class="product data items inline-flex gap-4 mb-4">
        <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
            <?php
            $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
            $label = $block->getChildData($alias, 'title');
            ?>
            <div class="data item title"
                 data-role="collapsible"
                 x-bind="{ 'active': activeTab === '<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>' }"
                 @click="activeTab = (activeTab === '<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>') ? false : '<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>'">
                <a class="data switch"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   data-toggle="trigger"
                   href="#<?= $block->escapeUrl($alias) ?>"
                   id="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title">
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $label ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $name): ?>
        <?php
        $html = $layout->renderElement($name);
        if (!$html || !trim($html)) {
            continue;
        }
        $alias = $layout->getElementAlias($name);
        ?>
        <div class="data item content"
             aria-labelledby="tab-label-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>-title"
             id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>"
             data-role="content"
             x-show="activeTab === '<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($alias) ?>'">
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $html ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```